# Timezone in Mule Quartz cron job

Tags: mule

I have a Mule flow with a `quartz:inbound-endpoint` that runs run every 15 minutes from 7 am to 6 pm every day. I want to run this job in US Eastern Time... How can I mention Time Zone with the job.

```
<flow name="quartzBasedDelivery">
    <quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="deliveryJob"
            cronExpression="*/15 07-18 * * ?">
        <quartz:endpoint-polling-job>
            <quartz:job-endpoint ref="testqueue" />
        </quartz:endpoint-polling-job>
    </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
    <logger message="QUARTZ found message for delivery #[payload]" level="INFO" />
</flow>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Quartz Cron Expression timezone is currently not configurable from the Mule endpoint (see/upvote: http://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-6799).

As a workaround you would have to patch `org.mule.transport.quartz.QuartzMessageReceiver` to support it.